# Titanium return last three inserted collections

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

i just want to know hot to display only last three collections inserted in titanium ?

```js
<View dataCollection="competence" dataFilter="filterFunction" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" layout="vertical" backgroundColor="gray" >
    <Label backgroundColor='red' height="Ti.UI.SIZE" text="{date_debut}"/>
    <Label backgroundColor='white' height="Ti.UI.SIZE" text="{date_fin}"/>
</View>
```

This display collections by 'ASC' from id order, my aim is only to show Three last elements.

I tried with dataFilter :

```js
function filterFunction(collection){
 // Underscore last method not working 
 return _.last(collection, 3);
 
}
```

Could you help me please ? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function filterFunction(collection){
    return _.last(collection.models, 3);
}
```